# Laravel Multiple Models Eloquent Relationships Setup?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I have 3 models

`User`
`Pick`
`Schedule`

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
$picksWhereGameStarted = User::find($user->id)
                                ->picks()
                                    ->where('week', $currentWeek)
                                    ->first()
                                ->schedule()
                                    ->where('gameTime', '<', Carbon::now())
                                    ->get();
```

This code only returns one array inside a collection. I want it to return more than 1 array if there is more than 1 result.

Can I substitute `->first()` with something else that will allow me to to return more than 1 results.

If not how can I set up my models relationship to allow this to work.

My models are currently set up as follow.

User model

```
public function picks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pick');
}
```

Schedule model

```
public function picks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pick');
}
```

Pick model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function schedule()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Schedule');
}
```

Comment: Your variable says `$picksWhereGameStarted` so are you trying to get `Pick`s? In your code, you're trying to get `User`s. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to get `Pick`s. I'm trying to do something like this. Get all `Pick`s from `User` with x id where game has started. So in the `users table` it looks for the `id` column then get all picks and then in `schedules table` it looks for the `gameTime` column to see if game has started.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a `User` model (you used it inside you `find` method as `$user->id`), you can just load its `Pick` relationship and load those `Pick`s' `Schedule` as follows:

**EDIT:**
Assuming you have a `schedules` table and your `picks` table has a `schedule_id` column. Try this.

```
$user->load(['picks' => function ($q) use ($currentWeek) {
    $q->join('schedules', 'picks.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
        ->where('schedules.gameTime', '<', Carbon::now()) // or Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'). See what works.
        ->where('picks.week', $currentWeek);
}])->load('picks.schedule');
```

**EDIT:** The code above should return the `user`'s `picks` which have a `schedules.gameTime < Carbon::now()`

Try it and do a dump of the `$user` object to see the loaded relationships. That's the `Eloquent` way you want.

Tip: you may want to do `$user->toArray()` before you dump `$user` to see the data better.

**EDIT:**
The loaded `picks` will be in a form of `Collections` so you'll have to access it using a loop. Try the following:

```php
foreach ($user->picks as $pick) {
    echo $pick->schedule->gameTime;
}
```

If you only want the first `pick` from the user you can do: `$user->picks->first()->schedule->gameTime`

Comment: I would like to do something like this `dd($user->picks()->schedule()->gamesStarted());` but I get a BadMethodCallException but if I do this `dd($user->picks()->first()->schedule()->gamesStarted());` that works but it's not what I'm looking for. I need all the picks where game has started and not just the first result.

Comment: Why do you use the `first()` method? It will only return the first element in the `picks` `Collection`. And is the `gamesStarted()` method a real method in the `Schedule` model? Or is it a field in your `schedules` table?

Answer (score 0):

I think a foreach loop may be what you're looking for:

```
$picks = User::find($user->id)->picks()->where('week', $currentWeek);
foreach ($picks as $pick){
    $pickWhereGameStarted = $pick->schedule()->where('gameTime', '<', Carbon::now())->get();
}
```

Try this and see if it's working for you

Comment: I can do that but I was hoping I can do it through Eloquent relationships. I would like to be able to run other functions besides `->get()` like `->count()` that is why I was looking for an Eloquent solution.